# Type class implementation for hierarchy

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am studying Scala and trying to implement some abstractions for custom types. Defining scalaz monoids for concrete classes is quite straightforward. But how to declare one Monoid for the type hierarchy? Assuming this code:

```
sealed trait Base
case class A(v:Int) extends Base
object N extends Base

object Main {
  // Wanna one monoid for all the Base's
  implicit val baseMonoid = new Monoid[Base] {
    override def append(f1: Base, f2: => Base): Base = f1 match {
      case A(x) => f2 match {
        case A(y) => A(x + y)
        case N => A(x)
      }
      case N => f2
    }
    override def zero = N
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(∅[Base] |+| A(3) |+| A(2)) // Compiles
    println(A(3) |+| A(2)) // Not compiles
  }
}
```

How to make state A() |+| B() workable in the example above?

Comment: Empty case classes are basically meaningless. You should see at least a warning when compiling this regarding that. Furthermore, your monoid implementation makes no sense. What is the point of trying to get something to compile which has no monoidal sense to it whatsoever? 

    case A() => f2 match {
            case A() => f2...

follows no monoid laws..

Comment: I know - the example above has no sense, but still - how to define such polymorphic monoid?

Comment: Okay, updated the example to make at least some sense.

Comment: see my answer and my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

sealed trait Base
case class A(a: Int) extends Base
case class B(b: Int) extends Base
object N extends Base

object BullShit {
  // Wanna one monoid for all the Base's

  implicit val sg: Semigroup[Base] = new Semigroup[Base] {
    override def append(f1: Base, f2: => Base): Base = f1 match {
      case A(a) => f2 match {
        case A(a1) => A(a + a1)
        case B(b) => A(a + b)
        case N => N
      }
      case B(b) => f2 match {
        case A(a) => B(a + b)
        case B(b1) => B(b + b1)
        case N => N
      }
      case N => f2
    }

  }

  println((A(1): Base) |+| (B(2): Base))
}
```

And your example would compile if you tell Scala's horrible type inferencer what you mean:

```
sealed trait Base
case class A(v: Int) extends Base
object N extends Base

object Main {
  // Wanna one monoid for all the Base's
  implicit val baseMonoid = new Monoid[Base] {
    override def append(f1: Base, f2: => Base): Base = f1 match {
      case A(x) => f2 match {
        case A(y) => A(x + y)
        case N => A(x)
      }
      case N => f2
    }
    override def zero = N
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import scalaz._, Scalaz._
    println(∅[Base] |+| A(3) |+| A(2)) // Compiles
    println((A(3): Base) |+| (A(2): Base)) // now it compiles
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't we somehow redefine a Monoid in such a way, that it matched for all the Base's implicitly?

Comment: @skapral you mean take some sealed trait and automatically define a Monoid instance for all the entire tree (trait + case classes extending it)? To my knowledge, no.